# How to interface Raspberry Pi 3B+ with peripheral board from different power source?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, raspberry-pi, ground-loop

As I mentioned in my question, I have an IO controller board with many digital/analog IOs, ADC IC and many relay units. It gets its power supply from a 12 V 5 A SMPS. The board has its own buck converter unit which splits 12 V to 5 V & 3.3 V respectively to provide power to each unit.

I want to control this IO board with my Raspberry Pi 3B+ GPIOs. I have a 5 V 2.5 A official power adapter to power up the RPi.

Now my question is, can I interface the RPi with the IO controller board safely? Or will there be any ground issue, though two power sources have different grounds?

Comment: they all need to have the same ground. also make sure your modules accept 3.3v inputs, many are 5v-only.

Comment: @dandavis so can I short the RPi ground to the controller board ground ?

Comment: "must", not "can". ok, well you could put optoisolators between everything, but there's no need as described.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: voltage is a relation of two points. you need a floor to support a ceiling. without a common ground, there's no way to know if a signal is 0v, 3v, 5v, or 100v. once the ground is common, 5v here is 5v there, and everything can talk, otherwise, it's floating in the breeze. sometimes we need tricks to isolate electrically but still communicate (for safety, EMI, etc) , in which case we use wireless, fiber optics, optocouplers, hall effects, etc, but the stuff you describe doesn't indicate such a need; it's just plain-jane DC componentry, which needs a common reference point we call ground.

Comment: @yeah,I got you. thank you. was also thinking the same but had some doubt you cleared it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it safely. You just have to connect the grounds of both Raspberry Pi and IO controller board so that both devices share a common ground.

Comment: I can connect both despite having two different power supply sources ! right?

Comment: Yes, you can connect them.

Comment: what if I connect the pi from onboard buck converter output. It can provide up to 3a current.

Comment: Yes, you can if you have a stable 5V output.

Comment: I have a stable5v but the question is how to give . it requires a micro usb b connector.

Comment: You can connect it to 5V on the header pins but beware that any increase in voltage or a current spike can fry your raspberry pi.

Comment: That means I have to chop off my data cable and then connect one end to pi and another end to  the headers